# Propagating view's dirty state to the containing form

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, controller

I have a main form with the following markup

```html
 <tabset vertical="true" type="pills">
                                    <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabsViews" select="selectView(tab.name, tab.index)"
                                         ng-show="tab.isVisible"
                                         class=" {{tabsViews[tab.index-1]['invalid'] ? 'invalid-tab': 'valid-tab' }}">
                                        <tab-heading>{{tab.title}}</tab-heading>
                                    </tab>
                                </tabset>
```

and the selectView method in my controller is the following:

```html
$scope.previousIndex = null;

            $scope.selectView = function (viewName, viewIndex) {
                $scope.selections.showInvoicesDetailView = false;
                $scope.selections.showInvoicesView = false;
                $scope.selections.showPassesView = false;
                if (viewIndex) {

                    if ($scope.previousIndex != null && $scope.form) {
                        $scope.tabsViews[$scope.previousIndex - 1]["invalid"] = $scope.form.$invalid;
                    }

                    $scope.previousIndex = viewIndex;
                }

                if (viewName.substring(0, 9) != 'invoices.')
                    $scope.selections.lastSelectedView = viewName;
                else
                    $scope.selections.showInvoicesDetailView = true;

                if (viewName == 'guestPasses')
                    $scope.selections.showPassesView = true;

                if (viewName == 'invoices')
                    $scope.selections.showInvoicesView = true;

                if ($scope.selections.isNew) {
                    window.console && console.log('SelectView called with the new.' + viewName + ' view...');
                    $state.go('new.' + viewName);
                }
                else {
                    window.console && console.log('SelectView called with the edit.' + viewName + ' view...');
                    $state.go('edit.' + viewName);
                }
            };
```

The main form has a directive to detect its dirty state and ask for saving the changes. The problem is that when I change anything in my current view, that form's dirty state is not propagated into that main form. Is there a way to set main form dirty state based on the particular tab (defined as the view) dirty state?

To understand the problem better, here is the main form markup (the one that has tabs):

```html
div ng-class="{'col-md-7': $parent.showSearch, 'col-md-11': !$parent.showSearch}">
    @Html.Partial("_EditFormHeader")
    <div class="fourpanel">
        <div data-sm:collapse="$parent.showForm" id="hideFrm" class="pull-left col-sm-3 sm-search-list">
            <form name="guestMainForm" novalidate role="form" data-sm:dirty-check data-server:error
                  ng-show="$parent.showForm && !selections.justDeleted" class="ng-cloak">
                <div id="guestEditForm" class="widget" data-resize:container>
                    <div class="widget-head">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            @Labels.guest: {{currentGuest.contactPerson.firstName + ' ' + currentGuest.contactPerson.lastName}} {{ !isNew ? '(' + currentGuest.guestNo + ')' : '' }}
                            <div class="pull-right text-right col-lg-1" style="padding-right:5px">
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-double-left sm-slider-button" ng-click="toggleFormVisibility()"
                                   alt="@String.Format(Labels.hideX, Labels.account)" id="angle-left"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="widget-content">
                        <div class="scrollable widget-resize">
                            <div class="padd">
                                @Html.Partial("_EditFormAlerts")
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 panel-container">
                                <tabset vertical="true" type="pills">
                                    <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabsViews" select="selectView(tab.name, tab.index)"
                                         ng-show="tab.isVisible"
                                         class=" {{tabsViews[tab.index-1]['invalid'] ? 'invalid-tab': 'valid-tab' }}">
                                        <tab-heading>{{tab.title}}</tab-heading>
                                    </tab>
                                </tabset>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-4 panel-container">
                                <div data-ui-view data-autoscroll="false"></div>
                                <div data-ui-view="guestPasses" ng-show="selections.showPassesView"></div>
                                <div data-ui-view="invoices" data-autoscroll="false" ng-show="selections.showInvoicesView"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="widget-foot">
                        <div ng-show="!isNew">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="save(currentGuest)"
                                    ng-disabled="form.$invalid || disableAction">
                                @Labels.save
                            </button>
                            <data-delete:button title="{{ '@Labels.delete: ' + currentGuest.contactPerson.firstName.trim() + ' ' + currentGuest.contactPerson.lastName.trim() + ' (' + currentGuest.guestNo +')' }}"
                                                message="@String.Format(Messages.confirmDelete, Labels.guest)"
                                                disable-action="disableAction"
                                                delete="delete()">
                            </data-delete:button>
                            <data-cancel:button title="@Labels.unsavedChanges"
                                                message="@Messages.unsavedChanges"
                                                cancel="cancel()"
                                                disable-action="disableAction"
                                                dirty="form.$dirty">
                            </data-cancel:button>
                        </div>
                        <div ng-show="isNew">
                            <button id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="new(currentGuest)"
                                    ng-disabled="form.$invalid || disableAction">
                                @Labels.add
                                </button>
                                <data-cancel:button title="@Labels.unsavedChanges"
                                                    message="@Messages.unsavedChanges"
                                                    cancel="cancel()"
                                                    disable-action="disableAction"
                                                    dirty="form.$dirty">
                                </data-cancel:button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
        </div>
        <div id="showFrm" class="sm-form-expand-button text-center col-sm-1"
             ng-show="!$parent.showForm"
             ng-click="toggleFormVisibility()">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>
            <div class="panel2Label">@Labels.guest: {{ currentGuest.contact.firstName.trim() + ' ' + currentGuest.contact.lastName.trim() }} {{ !isNew ? '(' + currentGuest.guestNo + ')' : '' }}</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-5 panel-container">
            <div data-ui-view="detail" data-autoscroll="true" ng-show="selections.showInvoicesDetailView"></div>
            <div data-ui-view="passDetail"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I created a new directive and added it to my view forms:

```html
function ($modal, $rootScope, $location, $state) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',
                require: ['^form'],
                //scope: {
                //    onOk: '&',
                //    onCancel: '&'
                //},
                link: function (scope, element, attrs, controllers) {

                    var form = controllers[0];

                    window.console && console.log(form);

                    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
                        if ((form && form.$dirty) || element.hasClass('ng-dirty')) {
                            //         return resourceFactory.getResource('Messages', 'unsavedChanges');

                            if (scope.form)
                            {
                                scope.form.$setDirty();
                            }
                        }
                    };
                   
                }
            };
```

I am debugging and I can see that form is correctly set to my view's form and I can access the parent form using form.$$parentForm property. However, I don't know to which event should I hook to set form.$$parentForm.$setDirty when my form becomes dirty. If you can help me figure this out, then it will work for me, I guess.

Comment: not directly related to answering your q, but you might consider including a console polyfill instead of feeling compelled to always do  `window.console && console.log(` https://github.com/paulmillr/console-polyfill

Answer (score 1):

Quote from Angular documentation on the form directive:

> In Angular, forms can be nested. This means that the outer form is valid when all of the child forms are valid as well. However, browsers do not allow nesting of  elements, so Angular provides the ngForm directive which behaves identically to  but can be nested. This allows you to have nested forms, which is very useful when using Angular validation directives in forms that are dynamically generated using the ngRepeat directive. Since you cannot dynamically generate the name attribute of input elements using interpolation, you have to wrap each set of repeated inputs in an ngForm directive and nest these in an outer form element.

Maybe this also works for the `$dirty` state so that if a child form is `$dirty` the parent form will also be `$dirty`. I'm not sure that in your case you'll be able to nest the forms. I don't have enough context to visualise what you want to achieve.

Alternatively, you can manually set the main form to dirty when one of those other forms becomes dirty. Because you added the code from your main form, I can see you're not using the built in dirty checker from angular. Maybe you have a good reason for this, but perhaps you didn't know of it's existence. You'll have to use the angular form directive then. The `FormController` has the following method: `$setDirty();`.

[FormController documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController)

[Form Directive documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form)

Comment: My "main" form is defined as just form, not ng-form. May be switching to ng-form can help? I may try that. I added main form markup into the question body

Comment: The main form has tabs. I defined a scope property tabViews. When I select a tab, I'm going to that particular view and the appropriate form is shown. I already had to play with invalid state to save and show correctly, now I have to find a way to get my main form state to be dirty when the current view is dirty

Comment: If using the form directive, you can use the `$setDirty()` function to make your form dirty. (updated original answer)

Comment: How can I detect the view dirty state to set main form dirty state? You saw my selectView method. From that view (individual form) how can I set the main form dirty? I know about the $setDirty, but I don't see from where exactly and how should I set it.

Comment: A way would be to set a 'dirty' flag in the `$rootScope` and when your 'view' gets dirty, you change this flag to true. When this flag is true, call the `$setDirty` from the main form.

Comment: I think we're talking about different things. My view (which is a tab form) gets dirty when something in that view is changed (in the interface user changes controls values). In my selectView method I need to somehow detect if that view has changed to set main form's flag. So, my question is - given the selectView code, how can I plug the view dirty state detection?

Comment: Do you know an event I can hook on to set dirty state of the parent form?
In other words, I added another directive to the view forms like this 
I am adding more content to my question.